# Authentication Issue : Google Cloud Endpoints with Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints, drive

We have implemented Firebase Google Authentication With Google Cloud Endpoints in our APIs . The code is going fine with all the APIs of our project.

But we are also using the Picker API JavaScript Library: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/ .

So when we attach any document from our drive, the Picker API prompts the Google sign-in once again, which is not done via Firebase but is the default one provided by the Picker API. The token returned for the same user via this Picker API is not the same as the ID token returned by the Firebase login. This makes the login not able to verify this user.

We are using this token to verify the Firebase one:

```
user = google.oauth2.id_token.verify_firebase_token(id_token, HTTP_REQUEST)
```

This gives us a 401 Unauthorized Error and our logs read the following : 
[image]

Comment: I don't see a question here. What is the token you are sending to Endpoints?

Comment: It would be quite interesting to know how you implemented Firebase Google Authentication With Google Cloud Endpoints. Any possibility to share your code or point to an example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding up to what it has been already commented, if you provide an example of what happens to you would be quite useful. On a side note, are you using the methods described [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users) to perform the authentication?

Comment: Hey @RenaudTarnec, you can find  [documentation here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.id_token.html).